# Android TableLayout.addView() does not really work

Tags: java, android, fragment, tablelayout

I'm trying to fill my TableLayout with some views with the method addView.

This is what I try to do:

```
private void createNewTable(){

  tableLayout = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
  for(int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++){
            if(objectList.get(i).getType() == 0){
                tableLayout.addView(createLocationObjectInTable((LocationObject)objectList.get(i)), i);
            }
  }
}
```

and the createObjectInList method:

```
private View createLocationObjectInTable(LocationObject locObject) {

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout, tr, false);

    TextView textViewCityName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_City_Name);
    TextView textViewCityProvider = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_City_Provider);
    textViewCityName.setText(locObject.getTitle());
    textViewCityProvider.setText(locObject.getSubTitle());

    return v;
}
```

But the views aren't displayed in the tableLayout. Logcat doesn't give me any error message, and when I try to do stuff after the line

```
tableLayout.addView(createLocationObjectInTable((LocationObject)objectList.get(i)), i);
```

nothing happend. The app just do nothing after this line.

Hope anyone can tell me my mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the TableRow view (tr) from you createLocationObjectInTable method instead of the inflated View v?

Comment: Even I return the tr, the view is not displayed. I call the method createNewtable() from an AsyncTask, maybe this caused some problems?

Answer (score 0):

You don't add your view to TableRow, instead you just add view to TableLayout. Try this:

```
private View createLocationObjectInTable(LocationObject locObject) {
    ...
    textViewCityProvider.setText(locObject.getSubTitle());

    tr.addView(v);
    return tr;
```

}

Comment: I tried this, but after I return the tr the TableLayout still not showing any view. The code after tableLayout.addView is also still not running, the app just stops.

Comment: @Sascha_ do you add your view to TableRow (`tr.addView(v);`)? And what 'just stops' mean? Activity doesn't start with no errors in LogCat?